# How do I integrate C++ library with Python?

Tags: c++, python, blender, berkelium

I want to integrate Berkelium (www.berkelium.org) with Blender to render browser in Blender scenes. Blender allows you to write python add-ons (http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions). I know only a little bit python what would be a good starting point for me? How do I call Berkelium methods in my python add-ons? Here is the link for Berkelium builds: https://github.com/sirikata/berkelium/downloads

Comment: One time I called C++ from Python using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org). But that was a long time ago .. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is covered by the python docs. Perhaps t[his will be of interest.](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html)