# Where do I find my -I/usr/local directory?

Tags: python, ubuntu, swig, filepath

I am trying to run this code sample to test swig on Ubuntu 12.04. I have python 2.7.3 installed on my system. This code seems to be for networked machines. How can I find where my python is installed and what should I replace these directory paths be?

```
cc -c example.c example_wrap.c \
-I/usr/local/include/python1.5 \
-I/usr/local/lib/python1.5/config
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the lines with `python-config --includes` which automatically creates the correct statements for the compiler and your installed python version. `python-config` itself is installed through `python-dev`, which you will need in case you haven't installed it yet.

So for calling the compiler on the command line:

```
cc -c example.c example_wrap.c $(python-config --cflags) -fPIC
```

Also, python1.5? Where did you find that example?

Comment: Thanks. It's swig tutorial from 1998. Actually I have already replaced python-dev tools but still there was no python.h in the address that is in the example. Also now I am getting following error: example_wrap.c:2952:21: fatal error: headers.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: There is a slightly newer tutorial at http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html. Still python2.1 ;) With my slightly edited command line, the example there works for me. If you want to interact with c-code from python, you can also take a look at http://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) That worked fine for me. Actually I am trying to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504795/how-do-i-integrate-c-library-with-python I want to integrate C++ library with Python. Any ideas on how it could be done?

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/local` is standard for any Posix operating system, see the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS)](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html).  You you get the python version you need with apt-get (I think the command is `sudo apt-get install python1.5` but I'm not on a ubuntu system at the moment so I can't try it), it will put it in the standard places, which is likely `/usr/local`.

To answer the other part of your question, you can find where your python is installed using `which python`.  `python` is likely a symbolic link to `python2.7`, so you may have to explicitly run `python1.5` which you can find with `which python1.5` if it's been installed.

Python 1.5 is a very, very old version of Python.  Where did you get the code sample from?